# How to saving groups and multi subgroups in laravel 7?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

Each group has several subgroups.

I have a `filters` table.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('filters', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('category_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->integer('parent_id');
        $table->string('name')->nullable();
        $table->string('latin')->nullable();
        $table->smallInteger('field')->nullable();
        $table->string('checkbox_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('color_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('color_code')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

create.blade.php

```
<form class="col-md-10" method="post" action="{{ route('filters.store') }}">
    @csrf
    <input type="hidden" name="category_id" value="{{ $category_id }}">
    <div id="showFilters">
        {{-- GROUP --}}
    </div>
    <a id="addFilter" class="bg-primary text-white pt-2 pb-2 pe-3 ps-3 rounded-circle cursor-pointer">
      <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
    </a>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">ذخیره</button>
</form>
```

script

```
'<input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="filters['+count+'][name]">'+
'<input type="text" id="latin" class="form-control" name="filters['+count+'][latin]">'+
'<select id="field" class="form-select field" name="filters['+count+'][field]">'+
'<option value="1">Check Box</option>'+
'<option value="2">Color</option>'+
'</select>'+
'<input type="text" id="checkbox_name" class="form-control" name="filters['+count+'][checkbox_name]">' +
'<input type="text" id="color_name" class="form-control" name="filters['+count+'][color_name]">'+
'<input type="text" id="color_code" class="form-control jscolor" name="filters['+count+'][color_code]">'+
```

And I have filters form like this.

[image: filters]

How to save `checkbox_name`, and `color_name` and `color_code`.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $filters = collect([]);
    if ($request->filters) {
        foreach ($request->filters as $filter) {
            if ($filter['name'] != null && $filter['field'] != null) {
                $model = Filter::updateOrCreate([
                    'id' => $request[0],
                ], [
                    'name' => $filter['name'],
                    'latin' => $filter['latin'],
                    'field' => $filter['field'],
                    'category_id' => $request->category_id,
                    'parent_id' => 0,
                ]);
                $filters->push($model);
            }
        }
    }
    Filter::whereNotIn('id', $filters->pluck('id'))->delete();
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

I see in the database but the `checkbox_name`, and `color_name` and `color_code`. are blank yet.

[image: DATEBASE]

#### My Question

How to save `parent_id` each subgroup to `id` of groups.

I want to save all  data in filters table. I do not want to save data in mutiple tables.

Comment: What is the problem with passing the parent id as hidden input?

Comment: @BartłomiejSobieszek- I did not understand your question –